# Countries gem rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, countries

I am using countries gem to list countries in a dropdown,

```
<%= form.collection_select(:country, ISO3166::Country.countries.sort_by(&:name), 'name', 'name', {include_blank: 'Select a country'}, class: "select__picker", 'data-style': 'form-control', required: true) %>
```

Is there any ways to display country name with country emoji at dropdown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a way.

```
<%= f.collection_select(:country, ISO3166::Country.countries.sort_by(&:name).collect { |c| [ c.name, "#{c.name} #{c.emoji_flag}" ] }, :first, :last, {include_blank: 'Select a country'}, class: "select__picker", 'data-style': 'form-control', required: true) %>
```

`collection_select` accepts only a method name as a `text_method` param.
The `text_method` is called on the `collection` param, which is:

```
ISO3166::Country.countries.sort_by(&:name).collect { |c| [ c.name, "#{c.name} #{c.emoji_flag}" ] }
```

So in your case, you are calling `:first` for the value and `:last` for the option text on:

```
[
  ['COUNTRY_1_NAME', 'COUNTRY_1_NAME COUNTRY_1_FLAG'],
  ['COUNTRY_2_NAME', 'COUNTRY_2_NAME COUNTRY_2_FLAG']
  etc.
]
```

Comment: :first for value_method and :last for text_method?